# What happens during Moksha?

Tags: moksha, death

What happens during Moksha, the end of all deaths?

I know already that the higher death is when the soul is reborn in a heavenly place but

- What about Moksha?
- What happens and what really Moksha is?

Comment: Moksha is Ending up your Jeeva in this world. Ending all the Karmas And surrendering ourselves to the supreme lord Narayana. In other words mukti. If one attains mukti, he ending the birth and death cycles in this world.

Comment: ok so to understand Moksha lets ask you a question. suppose today you get all the money in the world. you can do whatever you want. how happy you would be? very happy right? ok, suppose now you get all the riches, properties, wealth, of this world. You would be happiest isn't it!! But then suppose you have enjoyed this wealth for 60 years. Now you are 100 years old. You are going to leave this body anytime. What happens to all your wealth? Now are you happy? No. You are always thinking 'all the wealth is going to go'. One cannot take His wealth when He leaves the body right?

Comment: So what happens to all your happiness? gone. So money is not the cause of happiness. Then what is the cause of happiness? What is really permanent in this world? As you keep thinking like this, you understand that in this world nothing is permanent. So happiness from this world is not eternal. Moksha means Permanent Eternal Immortal Happiness. Happiness never goes. In hinduism, there are four different theories for this Happiness. According 1st theory, happiness is in you! Thus Moksha means realizing your true nature. According to 2nd theory, happiness is in God. Thus Moksha is to reach God.

Comment: According to 3rd theory, happiness is to serve God. Thus Moksha means to serve God. According to 4th theory, happiness can be given only by God. So Moksha is simply to surrender and let God grant that Happiness. This is a simplistic explanation of the four schools Advaita, Achintyabhedabheda, Dvaita and Vishista advaita. All the best sir!!

Answer (score 4):

Moksha is also called vimoksha, vimukti and mukti.

Moksh means free, let go, release, liberate.

For more click the below link

[Moksh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moksha)

Moksha-Sanyas Yog
Moksha in Hinduism and Jainism generally mean the same! In Christianity moksha is termed salvation...

The deeper meaning of moksha in Hinduism simply means liberation of the Atman soul from the cycle of birth and death forever! The moment human beings reached the stage of enlightenment (kaivalya jnana)... one finally gained moksha (salvation) in that lifetime!

Cessation of all karma in entirety results from reaching the stage of enlightenment... never before! Traveling the path of jnana yoga... assimilating the pearls of wisdom contained in sacred Bhagavad Gita of Hinduism... human beings finally emancipated forever from the cycle of birth and death... reached the stage of enlightenment (kaivalya jnana) and finally moksha (salvation)

Meaning of moksha as per Hindu traditions means gaining Mukti... liberation from the bondage of karma... from the vicious cycle of birth and death forever! This becomes possible when human beings after establishing absolute control over five senses and mind reached the stage of Nirvikalpa Samadhi... the stage of nothingness... the stage of absolute wisdom!

Answer (score 4):

Moksha is final liberation for an individual soul (jiva) from the cycle of birth and death. What moksha is exactly is defined differently by different philosophical schools of Hinduism, or more properly--Vedanta.

Those that follow the dualistic sects (dvaita), believe that moksha means the soul is liberated from the cycle of birth and death and are united in heaven for eternity with  a Personal God. Some sects believe that Shiva is the ultimate Godhead, others believe that Vishnu is the ultimate Godhead. The soul remains an individual entity for eternity living in peace and bliss with the personal Godhead.

Those that are qualified non-dualistic (visistadvaita) believe that the soul follows a different outcome in moksha. Professor P. N. Srinivasachari (in *The Spiritual Heritage of India*) describes it as follows:

> Release is not freedom in embodiment but freedom from embodiment; it refers to the return of the prakara or mukta [released soul] to his home in the absolute. [Ramanuja's absolute, however, is not the Absolute proper--but a personal God.] Mukti [freedom] is beyond the range of materialism and mentalism and involves the intuition of the infinite as well as its attainment. The finite has its roots in the infinite and in mukti there is the coalescence of content without the abolition of existence...The finite remains, but the fetters of finitude and individualism are removed.

So the soul realizes it is a part of the infinite Godhead, but remains eternally separate from the Godhead.

Those that follow the other school, the non-dualistic or advaita, believe that when moksha is attained the individual soul merges or dissolves into the Absolute Godhead. The individual soul ceases to exist. It is like a drop of water falling into the ocean. The nature of the advaita Godhead is Pure Consciousness. There is no more awareness of the universe of name and form. The universe ceases; there is only infinite peace, infinite bliss.

Comment: There is no sect of Dvaita Vedanta which considers Shiva the supreme god.  There is Shaiva Siddhanta, but that's not really part of the Vedantic tradition.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan My understanding of Shaivism is that all 3 philosophies (dvaita, visistadvaita, and advaita) exist within Shaivism. Shaiva Siddhanta are Hindus. They follow the Vedas. There is a math in the US that is one of the most vocal supporters of Hinduism in the West. See http://www.hinduismtoday.com/

Comment: Yeah, of course Shaivites are Hindus.  I'm just saying that they're not really part of the Vedanta school.  Shaiva Siddhanta believes in some sort of difference between the Jivatma and Shiva, but it does not actually subscribe to Dvaita Vedanta.

Comment: In any case, you're right that there are Visistadvaitin Shaivites, known as the Shiva Advaita philosophy of Shrikantha.  But what sect of Shaivites follows Advaita Vedanta?  There are Advaitins who call themselves Shiavites, specifically Iyer Brahmins, but they're just Smarthas who have Shiva as their personal god.  The only monistic Shaivite sect I know of is the Naths, but they're not Vedantic.  They're not even part of the Astika tradition.

Comment: No scriptural quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You got it right. Moksha means getting rid of life and death cycle and never to be reborn in any species (yoni) and living forever in heavenly abode. That is the only way one can truely get rid of all the pains and sorrows of life.

Hindu scriptures describe ways to attain moksha. If you have seen any of 'Ramcharitmanas' or 'Ramayan', there is a character called 'Jatayu' (a bird) who got moksha or mukti from lord Ram because of his supreme sacrifice for good of others.

All of this is based on personal experience.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.